# How to speed up python instance initialization for millions of objects?

Tags: python, performance, instance

I have defined a python `class` named `Edge` as follows:

```
class Edge:
    def __init__(self):
        self.node1 = 0
        self.node2 = 0
        self.weight = 0
```

Now I have to create approximately 10^6 to 10^7 instances of Edge using:

```
edges= []
for (i,j,w) in ijw:
    edge = Edge()
    edge.node1 = i
    edge.node2 = j
    edge.weight = w
    edges.append(edge)
```

I took me approximately 2 seconds in Desktop. Is there any faster way to do?

Comment: In addition to the approach based on `__slots__`, there is another one based on the `recordclass` library. It is applicable in the case when instances of classes are created that de facto do not participate in reference cycles. This is the case for simple record-like objects. It allows to reduce memory consumption and reduce the time to create objects. Details in my answer below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't make it *much* faster, but I certainly would use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to save on memory allocations. Also make it possible to pass in the attribute values when creating the instance:

```
class Edge:
    __slots__ = ('node1', 'node2', 'weight')
    def __init__(self, node1=0, node2=0, weight=0):
        self.node1 = node1
        self.node2 = node2
        self.weight = weight
```

With the updated `__init__` you can use a list comprehension:

```
edges = [Edge(*args) for args in ijw]
```

Together these can shave off a decent amount of time creating the objects, roughly halve the time needed.

Comparison creating 1 million objects; the setup:

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> ijw = [(randrange(100), randrange(100), randrange(1000)) for _ in range(10 ** 6)]
>>> class OrigEdge:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.node1 = 0
...         self.node2 = 0
...         self.weight = 0
...
>>> origloop = '''\
... edges= []
... for (i,j,w) in ijw:
...     edge = Edge()
...     edge.node1 = i
...     edge.node2 = j
...     edge.weight = w
...     edges.append(edge)
... '''
>>> class SlotsEdge:
...     __slots__ = ('node1', 'node2', 'weight')
...     def __init__(self, node1=0, node2=0, weight=0):
...         self.node1 = node1
...         self.node2 = node2
...         self.weight = weight
...
>>> listcomploop = '''[Edge(*args) for args in ijw]'''
```

and the timings:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> count, total = Timer(origloop, 'from __main__ import OrigEdge as Edge, ijw').autorange()
>>> (total / count) * 1000 # milliseconds
722.1121070033405
>>> count, total = Timer(listcomploop, 'from __main__ import SlotsEdge as Edge, ijw').autorange()
>>> (total / count) * 1000 # milliseconds
386.6706900007557
```

That's nearly 2 times as fast.

Increasing the random input list to 10^7 items, and the timing difference holds:

```
>>> ijw = [(randrange(100), randrange(100), randrange(1000)) for _ in range(10 ** 7)]
>>> count, total = Timer(origloop, 'from __main__ import OrigEdge as Edge, ijw').autorange()
>>> (total / count)
7.183759553998243
>>> count, total = Timer(listcomploop, 'from __main__ import SlotsEdge as Edge, ijw').autorange()
>>> (total / count)
3.8709938440006226
```

Comment: Will [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) do anything for instantiation speed?

Comment: @Tomalak: dataclasses are not special; it's just code generation. Dataclasses actually [do not support generating `__slots__` at this point](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#support-for-automatically-setting-slots), so no, they won't make any difference.

Comment: For the record, some optimization seems to be there. I've tested based on your code and found that dataclasses take 75% the time of the original loop.

Comment: For a class as simple as this I would suggest using a `namedtuple`. Might be even faster...

Comment: @Tomalak: I can't reproduce that; I get the same timings for `Slots` defined as dataclass as without it. And trust me, dataclasses really can't optimise this further.

Comment: @martineau: it is no faster; a namedtuple also uses slots.

Comment: Curious, I can reproduce it consistently on my machine. I've used your code, plus the most basic @dataclass annotated class with 3 int fields, but without defining `__slots__`.

Comment: Martijn: I didn't say smaller, I said faster. Aren't `nametuple`s implemented in C nowadays?

Comment: Here's the code I am using: https://gist.github.com/Tomalak/5a83ced5387db227bdbeb886507300d4

Comment: @martineau: I did mean faster; the speed here comes from avoiding larger memory block allocations. `namedtuple` is a code generator for a subclass of `tuple`, and it generates Python code for the constructor. Constructing a namedtuple-generated class instance is no faster.

Comment: @Tomalak: your dataclass code confirms my timings. It's the same speed as the slots example (the timings are the same within a margin). I may have misunderstood what your 75% was relative to here; the non-slots dataclass speedup is purely due to the list comprehension, not due to you using a dataclass. If you used my class without `__slots__` but with the list comp, you'd get the same timings.

Comment: I know it _can_ generate equivalent Python source, but assumed that internally it wasn't doing that and at least some of it was implemented in C. Regardless, either way it's a subclass of the built-in `tuple` type, which I pretty sure is written in C. (Obviously I'm talking about CPython.)

Comment: @martineau: in fact, a `namedtuple`-based class would be *larger* because it has to record the tuple size. `SlotsEdge` instances take 64 bytes on my system, a `namedtuple` generated `NTEdge` takes 72 bytes. That doesn't impact object creation all that much here, but the extra 8 bytes times 10 million does affect memory pressure.

Comment: @martineau: yes, `tuple` is written in C. But the [generated code consists of a `__new__` method, written in Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/260ec2c36abd73bac51489108409160427979ede/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L384-L395). It has to call `tuple.__new__()` to produce the tuple data structure. The slots code here has a `__init__` instead, and assigns three attributes. That's just way too little difference to matter.

Comment: Martijn: OK, I'm convinced. But when I have a chance tomorrow, I'm going to time a `namedtuple` version just to see how it compares speedwise.

Comment: @martineau: See https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/a4d01024f50d56210dceefc1acdbd487 for timings and memory footprint.

Comment: Martijn: Thanks for doing the timing for me...and your for answer generally—I've found it very enlightening. One big takeaway is that a simple "slotted" Python class is better than a `namedtuple` both in terms of speed and memory usage—two of main reasons I've used them to do things similar to this question's topic in the past.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - shouldn't `__slots__` be a list? Seems to cause issues when using () rather than []

Comment: @kindjacket: no, `__slots__` [*can be assigned a string, iterable, or sequence of strings with variable names used by instances.*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__slots__). Both a tuple and a list are iterables.

Comment: Brilliant. I needed to quickly initialize one object. Went from 130ms to 2ms.

Answer (score 4):

There is another fast and memory saving method using [recordclass library](https://bitbucket.org/intellimath/recordclass):

```
from recordclass import dataobject

from random import randrange
import sys
ijw = [(randrange(100), randrange(100), randrange(1000)) for _ in range(10 ** 7)]

class EdgeDO(dataobject):
    __fields__ = 'node1', 'node2', 'weight'

class EdgeSlots:
    __slots__ = 'node1', 'node2', 'weight'

    def __init__(self, node1, node2, weight):
         self.node1 = node1
         self.node2 = node2
         self.weight = weight
            
def list_size(lst):
    return sum(sys.getsizeof(o) for o in lst)

%time list_do = [EdgeDO(n1, n2, w) for n1, n2, w in ijw]
%time list_slots = [EdgeSlots(n1, n2, w) for n1, n2, w in ijw]

print('size (dataobject):', list_size(list_do))
print('size (__slots__): ', list_size(list_slots))
```

There is the output:

```
CPU times: user 2.23 s, sys: 20 ms, total: 2.25 s
Wall time: 2.25 s
CPU times: user 6.79 s, sys: 84.1 ms, total: 6.87 s
Wall time: 6.87 s
size (dataobject): 400000000
size (__slots__):  640000000
```

P.S. Since 0.15 there is option `fast_new` for faster instance creation. Since 0.18 `fast_new=True` by default. Below new performance counters for python 3.9, 64 bit.

```
from random import randrange
import sys
ijw = [(randrange(100), randrange(100), randrange(1000)) for _ in range(10 ** 7)]

class EdgeDO(dataobject, fast_new=True):
    __fields__ = 'node1', 'node2', 'weight'

class EdgeSlots:
    __slots__ = 'node1', 'node2', 'weight'

    def __init__(self, node1, node2, weight):
         self.node1 = node1
         self.node2 = node2
         self.weight = weight
        
def list_size(lst):
    return sum(sys.getsizeof(o) for o in lst)

print('dataobject timinig:')
%time list_do = [EdgeDO(*args) for args in ijw]
print('__slots__ timinig:')
%time list_slots = [EdgeSlots(*args) for args in ijw]

print('size (dataobject):', list_size(list_do))
print('size (__slots__): ', list_size(list_slots))
print(list_size(list_do)/list_size(list_slots)*100, "%")
```

Results:

```
dataobject timinig:
CPU times: user 804 ms, sys: 16 ms, total: 820 ms
Wall time: 819 ms
__slots__ timinig:
CPU times: user 5.54 s, sys: 23.9 ms, total: 5.56 s
Wall time: 5.56 s
size (dataobject): 400000000
size (__slots__):  560000000
71.42857142857143 %
```

Comment: Is this a drop-in replacement for `dataclass`? What are the downsides of switching from `dataclass` to `dataobject`?

Comment: First `recordclass` is an C-extension. Some of people want to use native solution (builtin type or library). Second it doesn't a replacement of `dataclass` because `dataobject`-based classes have specific metaclass `datatype`, which can limit possibilities in multiple inheritance scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to skip the `Edge` class and implement the edges via a table, or adjacency matrix.

E.g.

```
A = create_adjacency_graph(ijw)  # Implement to return a IxJ (sparse?) matrix of weights
edge_a_weight = A[3, 56]
edge_b_weight = A[670, 1023]
# etc...
```

This does remove some flexibility though, but should be quite fast both to create and use.

Comment: In my case, I will pass them into other functions, in order to improve code readability, I prefer using class.

Comment: @ted930511 : To run any algorithm on huge data, you must think at more efficient data structure/language, unless it is a prototype.