# What is the fastest way to instantiate this Python class a million times?

Tags: python, performance, loops

Given I have a class:

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, flag=None):
        self.a = list()
        self.b = {}
        self.c = 0
        self.d = 1
        self.e = defaultdict(list)
        self.f = defaultdict(set)
        if flag is None:
            self.g = False
        else:
            self.g = flag
        self.something_else = (1,1,1)

    def foo(self):  # many other heavy methods
        self.a.append(self.d + self.c)
        return self.e
```

I need to instantiate it 1,000,000 times and then call `foo()`. What is the fastest way to do? Can it be done even faster with CFFI

e.g.

```py
l = []
for i in range(10000000):
   o = C()
   l.append(o)
```

Comment: `objs = [C() for _ in range(10000000)]` is about as fast as I'd imagine you can get. Maybe switch languages or use a JIT compiler? Why is the current code not fast enough for you (please provide context/use case)?

Comment: Did you try to run it with [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/)? Not sure if this will be much faster, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Split the work between processes?

Comment: @ggorlen the program is like 20k+ likes of code and does these type of instantiations millions of times per run. I am thinking about creating a pre-allocated object pool but it makes no sense if I wouldn't be able to allocate like 1000x the current speed

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to systematically call methods on every instance, you may want to defer initialization to the first call to another method.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class C:
    def __init__(self, flag=None):
        self.initDone = False
        self.g = False if flag is None else flag

    def competeInit(self):
        if self.initDone: return
        self.a = list()
        self.b = {}
        self.c = 0
        self.d = 1
        self.e = defaultdict(list)
        self.f = defaultdict(set)
        self.something_else = (1,1,1)

    def foo(self):  # many other heavy methods
        self.completeInit()
        self.a.append(self.d + self.c)
        return self.e
```

This makes allocating 10M instances roughly 5 times faster.

```
A = [C() for _ in range(10000000)] # 3.95 sec vs 20.4
```

Depending on usage patterns, this may postpone the cost of initialization to a more acceptable time or even as a background process.

Alternatively you could postpone only the more costly parts of the initialization using properties for lists, dictionary and set attributes:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class C:
    def __init__(self, flag=None):
        self.initDone = False
        self.g  = False if flag is None else flag
        self.c  = 0
        self.d  = 1
        self.something_else = (1,1,1)

    def foo(self):  # many other heavy methods
        self.a.append(self.d + self.c)
        return self.e

    @property
    def a(self):
        try: return self._a
        except AttributeError:
            self._a = list()
            return self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        try: return self._b
        except AttributeError:
            self._b = {}
            return self._b

    @property
    def e(self):
        try: return self._e
        except AttributeError:
            self._e = defaultdict(list)
            return self._e

    @property
    def f(self):
        try: return self._e
        except AttributeError:
            self._f = defaultdict(set)
            return self._f
```

In this case, it only gives a 4x speed improvement though

```
A = [C() for _ in range(10000000)] # 5.16 sec vs 20.4
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using Python's `multiprocessing`?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def instantiate_and_run(x):
    return C()

with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
    l = pool.map(instantiate_and_run, range(1000000))
```

Comment: `cpu_count` is the default number of processes of a `Pool`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo [PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2)

Comment: instantiating in separate processes, then merging back into main thread would actually require to virtually instantiate twice and will end up slower than in single process

Answer (score 0):

This seems a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388451/how-to-speed-up-python-instance-initialization-for-millions-of-objects)

In python you can use [slots](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to speed up creation, maybe a little bit, and the memory occupation. Migrate that class to a slot is very trivial.

another solution was [record class](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/) it is designe to optimize  creation of new instances.